# What is the meaning of もう and もじ?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, meaning, words

> わたしのむすめは**もうもじ**をよむことができます。

What is the meaning of もう and もじ?

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: It can be kanji - もう**文字**を読むことが〜

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**もう** can mean different things depending on context like already/yet/anymore and **もじ** (文字) means a character.

私{わたし}の娘｛むすめ｝はもう文字｛もじ｝を読｛よ｝むことが出来｛でき｝ます。

Assuming the preceding kanji, I would translate the sentence to "My daughter can **already** read **characters**".